# Can't get HTTP response from particular server

Tags: networking

Three times in the past 24 hours and once before, I've lost my ability to connect to the server that hosts the Arch forums as well as the Wiki and AUR.

When connecting with a browser, the connection times out. I tried `curl -v` and got `Network is unreachable`.

I can `ping` and `traceroute` the address with no errors, but HTTP just doesn't come through.

It happens (seemingly) at random, and only time seems to fix it.

This isn't really an Arch issue per se. It affects my entire network, but it's only this one server. Someone on #archlinux thought that it might've been DNS caching, but curl says that it's not there.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I tried changing my DNS to Google's public server to no avail. So, it doesn't seem to be that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to connect to send an HTTP request to the IP address instead of the DNS name? 
Can you access the address at the same time from another connection, e.g. via your phone's?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, and to no avail. As stated in the OP "It affects my entire network," so connecting from another device proves just as useless.